# Cannot insert data into an Azure SQL Database using Azure Functions

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, azure-functions

I would like to insert rows into my Azure SQL Database using an Azure Function. The error I am getting is

> RequestError: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrgName', table 'ICTDatabase.dbo.Postings'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

[while my request body is sending the required data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zl39.png) (all the data in this request body is fake).

This is the code for the Azure Function (coded in Node.js):

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('postToICTSQLDatabasePostings', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`HTTP function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        // Get the request body directly as a JavaScript object
        const requestBody = request.body;

        // Get the database connection details from the environment variables
        const config = {
            server: process.env.DB_SERVER,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            options: {
                encrypt: true, // for azure
                trustServerCertificate: false
            },
        };

        try {
            // Create a new connection
            let pool = await sql.connect(config);

            // Add console logging
            context.log(`OrgName: ${requestBody.orgName}`);
            context.log(`ContactName: ${requestBody.contactName}`);
            context.log(`PhoneNum: ${requestBody.phoneNum}`);
            context.log(`StartDate: ${requestBody.startDate}`);
            context.log(`PostID: ${requestBody.postID}`);
            context.log(`PostTitle: ${requestBody.postTitle}`);
            context.log(`PostDesc: ${requestBody.postDesc}`);
            context.log(`ProgramType: ${requestBody.programType}`);
            context.log(`PostType: ${requestBody.postType}`);
            context.log(`Files: ${requestBody.files}`);
            context.log(`Status: ${requestBody.status}`);
            context.log(`Email: ${requestBody.email}`);
            context.log(`Season: ${requestBody.season}`);

            // Prepare the SQL request
            const request = new sql.Request(pool);
            await request.input('orgName', sql.VarChar, requestBody.orgName);
            await request.input('contactName', sql.VarChar, requestBody.contactName);
            await request.input('phoneNum', sql.VarChar, requestBody.phoneNum);
            await request.input('startDate', sql.VarChar, requestBody.startDate);
            await request.input('postID', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postID);
            await request.input('postTitle', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postTitle);
            await request.input('postDesc', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postDesc);
            await request.input('programType', sql.VarChar, requestBody.programType);
            await request.input('postType', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postType);
            await request.input('files', sql.VarChar, requestBody.files);
            await request.input('status', sql.VarChar, requestBody.status);
            await request.input('email', sql.VarChar, requestBody.email);
            await request.input('season', sql.VarChar, requestBody.season);

            // Execute the SQL query to insert the data into the postings table
            await request.query(`
                INSERT INTO Postings (OrgName, ContactName, PhoneNum, StartDate, PostID, PostTitle, PostDesc, ProgramType, PostType, Files, Status, Email, Season)
                VALUES (@orgName, @contactName, @phoneNum, @startDate, @postID, @postTitle, @postDesc, @programType, @postType, @files, @status, @email, @season)
            `);

            return {
                status: 200,
                body: "Data inserted successfully",
            };
        } catch (err) {
            context.log(`Error: ${err}`);
            return {
                status: 500,
                body: err,
            };
        } finally {
            sql.close(); // close the connection
        }
    }
});
```

And the Vue function that is sending the request to the Azure function is also here (ICTFileUpload is working perfectly, postToICTSQLDatabasePostings is not):

```
    const submitForm = () => {
      if (!orgName.value || !contactName.value || !phoneNum.value || !startDate.value || !postTitle.value || !postDesc.value || !programType.value || !email.value || !season.value) {
        toast.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Please fill out the form correctly.', life: 3000 });
      } else {
        const formData = new FormData();
        let fileNames = []; // Create an array to store file names
        fileObjects.value.forEach((file, index) => {
          formData.append('file', file, fileName.value[index]); // Append the File object
          fileNames.push(fileName.value[index]); // Add the file name to the array
        });

        axios.post('https://REDACTED.azurewebsites.net/api/ICTFileUpload', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
          .then(response => {
            // Handle success
            console.log(response);
            toast.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Form submitted successfully.', life: 3000 });

            // Generate a random 6 digit number for the PostID
            const postID = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);

            // Automatically set the status to "Open" when the form is submitted
            const status = 'Open';

            // Send another POST request to the Azure Function URL
            const postData = {
            OrgName: orgName.value,
            ContactName: contactName.value,
            PhoneNum: phoneNum.value,
            StartDate: startDate.value,
            PostID: postID,
            PostTitle: postTitle.value,
            PostDesc: postDesc.value,
            ProgramType: programType.value,
            PostType: programType.value,
            Files: fileNames.join(','), // Send the file names as a comma-separated string
            Status: status,
            Email: email.value,
            Season: season.value
          };

            // Print the POST data to the console
            console.log(postData);

            return axios.post('https://REDACTED.azurewebsites.net/api/postToICTSQLDatabasePostings', postData, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
            });
          })
          .then(response => {
            // Handle success of the second POST request
            console.log(response);
            toast.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Data inserted successfully.', life: 3000 });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Handle error
            console.log(error);
            toast.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Error', detail: 'Failed to submit the form.', life: 3000 });
          });
      }
    };
```

Any help with this is appreciated. Thank you very much.

I have already tried changing the capitalization in the `requestBody` in the Azure Function (`orgName` to `OrgName`)

Comment: Ensure that you are correctly handling the data in your Azure Function before attempting to insert it into the database

Comment: @AllanRomanato How would I be able to do that, please?

Comment: in log are you getting the values or getting `undefined`?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya I am getting undefined, yes. Even when I send the request with the JSON body using Postman.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript Programming model v4 values are not fetched from the Json, which is resulting in `undefined` value and the null value error.

## Model v3

I was able to Insert data in using model v3.

**#My Code :**
**`HttpTrigger1/index.js`:**

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    context.log('Node.js HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri=%s', req.originalUrl);
    const requestBody = req.body;

        // Get the database connection details from the environment variables
        const config = process.env["Connection_string"];

        try {
            
            // Add console logging
            context.log(`OrgName: %s`, requestBody.orgName);
            context.log(`ContactName: %s`,requestBody.contactName);
            context.log(`PhoneNum:%s`,requestBody.phoneNum);
            context.log(`StartDate: %s`,requestBody.startDate);
            context.log(`PostID: %s`,requestBody.postID);
            context.log(`PostTitle: %s`,requestBody.postTitle);
            context.log(`PostDesc: %s`,requestBody.postDesc);
            context.log(`ProgramType: %s`,requestBody.programType);
            context.log(`PostType: %s`,requestBody.postType);
            context.log(`Files: %s`,requestBody.files);
            context.log(`Status: %s`,requestBody.status);
            context.log(`Email: %s`,requestBody.email);
            context.log(`Season: %s`,requestBody.season);


            // Create a new connection
            let pool = await sql.connect(config);

            // Prepare the SQL request
            const request = new sql.Request(pool);
            await request.input('orgName', sql.VarChar, requestBody.orgName);
            await request.input('contactName', sql.VarChar, requestBody.contactName);
            await request.input('phoneNum', sql.VarChar, requestBody.phoneNum);
            await request.input('startDate', sql.VarChar, requestBody.startDate);
            await request.input('postID', sql.Int, requestBody.postID);
            await request.input('postTitle', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postTitle);
            await request.input('postDesc', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postDesc);
            await request.input('programType', sql.VarChar, requestBody.programType);
            await request.input('postType', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postType);
            await request.input('files', sql.VarChar, requestBody.files);
            await request.input('status', sql.VarChar, requestBody.status);
            await request.input('email', sql.VarChar, requestBody.email);
            await request.input('season', sql.VarChar, requestBody.season);

            // Execute the SQL query to insert the data into the postings table
            await request.query(`
                INSERT INTO Postings (OrgName, ContactName, PhoneNum, StartDate, PostID, PostTitle, PostDesc, ProgramType, PostType, Files, Status, Email, Season)
                VALUES (@orgName, @contactName, @phoneNum, @startDate, @postID, @postTitle, @postDesc, @programType, @postType, @files, @status, @email, @season)
            `);

            context.res ={
                status: 200,
                body: "Data inserted successfully",
            };
        } catch (err) {
            context.log(`Error: %s`,err);
            context.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: err,
            };
        } finally {
            sql.close(); // close the connection
        }
};
```

**`HttpTrigger1/function.json`:**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`INPUT`:**

```json
{
  "orgName": "Sample Organization",
  "contactName": "Vivek Shandilya",
  "phoneNum": "123-456-7890",
  "startDate": "2024-02-10",
  "postID": 123456,
  "postTitle": "Sample Post Title",
  "postDesc": "This is a sample post description. It can be longer and more detailed.",
  "programType": "Sample Program",
  "postType": "Sample Type",
  "files": "file1.txt,file2.docx,file3.pdf",
  "status": "Open",
  "email": "vivek.shandilya@example.com",
  "season": "Spring"
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

```
Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-06T10:01:16.586Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.331Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=4693fa05-379f-4371-b080-6eaac8d0f100)
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.492Z] OrgName: Sample Organization
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.492Z] Node.js HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri=http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.492Z] PhoneNum:123-456-7890
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.492Z] ContactName: Vivek Shandilya
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] PostDesc: This is a sample post description. It can be longer and more detailed.
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] PostTitle: Sample Post Title
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] Status: Open
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] Email: vivek.shandilya@example.com
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.492Z] PostID: 123456
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] ProgramType: Sample Program
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] Season: Spring
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.492Z] StartDate: 2024-02-10
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] PostType: Sample Type
[2024-02-06T10:06:49.497Z] Files: file1.txt,file2.docx,file3.pdf
[2024-02-06T10:07:18.164Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=4693fa05-379f-4371-b080-6eaac8d0f100, Duration=28869ms)
```

[image]

```
Data inserted successfully
```

[image]

[image]

## EDIT

## In Model V4:

This worked for me. For reference check this [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/azure-functions-version-4-of-the-node-js-programming-model-is-in/ba-p/3773541).

I used `const requestBody = await request.json();`

#My Code

**`httpTrigger1.js`:**

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`HTTP function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        // Get the request body directly as a JavaScript object
        const requestBody = await request.json();

        // Get the database connection details from the environment variables
        const config = process.env.Connection_String;

        try {
            // Create a new connection
            let pool = await sql.connect(config);

            // Add console logging
            context.log(`OrgName: ${requestBody.orgName}`);
            context.log(`ContactName: ${requestBody.contactName}`);
            context.log(`PhoneNum: ${requestBody.phoneNum}`);
            context.log(`StartDate: ${requestBody.startDate}`);
            context.log(`PostID: ${requestBody.postID}`);
            context.log(`PostTitle: ${requestBody.postTitle}`);
            context.log(`PostDesc: ${requestBody.postDesc}`);
            context.log(`ProgramType: ${requestBody.programType}`);
            context.log(`PostType: ${requestBody.postType}`);
            context.log(`Files: ${requestBody.files}`);
            context.log(`Status: ${requestBody.status}`);
            context.log(`Email: ${requestBody.email}`);
            context.log(`Season: ${requestBody.season}`);

            // Prepare the SQL request
            const request = new sql.Request(pool);
            await request.input('orgName', sql.VarChar, requestBody.orgName);
            await request.input('contactName', sql.VarChar, requestBody.contactName);
            await request.input('phoneNum', sql.VarChar, requestBody.phoneNum);
            await request.input('startDate', sql.VarChar, requestBody.startDate);
            await request.input('postID', sql.Int, requestBody.postID);
            await request.input('postTitle', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postTitle);
            await request.input('postDesc', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postDesc);
            await request.input('programType', sql.VarChar, requestBody.programType);
            await request.input('postType', sql.VarChar, requestBody.postType);
            await request.input('files', sql.VarChar, requestBody.files);
            await request.input('status', sql.VarChar, requestBody.status);
            await request.input('email', sql.VarChar, requestBody.email);
            await request.input('season', sql.VarChar, requestBody.season);

            // Execute the SQL query to insert the data into the postings table
            await request.query(`
                INSERT INTO Postings (OrgName, ContactName, PhoneNum, StartDate, PostID, PostTitle, PostDesc, ProgramType, PostType, Files, Status, Email, Season)
                VALUES (@orgName, @contactName, @phoneNum, @startDate, @postID, @postTitle, @postDesc, @programType, @postType, @files, @status, @email, @season)
            `);

            return {
                status: 200,
                body: "Data inserted successfully",
            };
        } catch (err) {
            context.log(`Error: ${err}`);
            return {
                status: 500,
                body: err,
            };
        } finally {
            sql.close(); // close the connection
        }
    }
});
```

**`INPUT`:**
I just changed the `postID` Value to `654321` all other values are same.

```json
{
  "orgName": "Sample Organization",
  "contactName": "Vivek Shandilya",
  "phoneNum": "123-456-7890",
  "startDate": "2024-02-10",
  "postID": 654321,
  "postTitle": "Sample Post Title",
  "postDesc": "This is a sample post description. It can be longer and more detailed.",
  "programType": "Sample Program",
  "postType": "Sample Type",
  "files": "file1.txt,file2.docx,file3.pdf",
  "status": "Open",
  "email": "vivek.shandilya@example.com",
  "season": "Spring"
}
```

## `OUTPUT`:

```
Functions:

        httpTrigger1: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-06T17:06:35.391Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-02-06T17:06:45.095Z] Executing 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=e7dcec5e-23e5-450d-8c97-67a8717cd2ee)
[2024-02-06T17:06:45.229Z] HTTP function processed request for url "http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger1"
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.066Z] OrgName: Sample Organization
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.066Z] ContactName: Vivek Shandilya
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.072Z] PhoneNum: 123-456-7890
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.072Z] PostID: 654321
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.073Z] PostDesc: This is a sample post description. It can be longer and more detailed.
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.074Z] ProgramType: Sample Program
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.073Z] PostTitle: Sample Post Title
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.072Z] StartDate: 2024-02-10
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.075Z] PostType: Sample Type
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.076Z] Files: file1.txt,file2.docx,file3.pdf
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.079Z] Status: Open
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.082Z] Season: Spring
[2024-02-06T17:06:47.080Z] Email: vivek.shandilya@example.com
[2024-02-06T17:06:49.571Z] Executed 'Functions.httpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=e7dcec5e-23e5-450d-8c97-67a8717cd2ee, Duration=4508ms)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there no possible way to do it with v4?

Comment: @getzucked Updated answer for `model V4`